# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mtbelano_Helper_Data' when loading page

Tags: php, magento

I'm helping my brother but unfortunately, I'm very very new to Magento but I'm good in PHP and Unix.

I would like to ask what this error is and how to fix it.

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mtbelano_Helper_Data' not found in /home/scott/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: How are you helping if you're very *very* new? Also can you post the code for the application? Also a stack trace wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Found out they manually used an existing site and just renamed directories. Still hunting the issue. Might be inside an xml configuration or in stored deeply in the database.